# New Thread is causing ContextNotActiveException

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, wicket

I'm trying to start a new thread in a Wicket framework app and I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:598)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:71)
```

This new thread is in a web service as follow:

```
@GET
@Override
@Path("notificarPadres")
public String notificarPadres(@QueryParam("centroDeCostosId") Integer centroDeCostosId, @QueryParam("userNotificadorId") String userNotificadorId, @QueryParam("mensaje") final String mensaje) {
    String result = GradienteConstants.STRING_TRUE;

    final Set<User> destinatarios = new HashSet<User>();
    List<CentroDeCostos> listCentroCostoPadres = listCentroDeCostosPadresById(String.valueOf(centroDeCostosId));
    final User notificador = getUserById(userNotificadorId.toLowerCase());

    for (CentroDeCostos centroCosto : listCentroCostoPadres) {
        if (hasCentroDeCostoResponsable(centroCosto)) {
            User responsable = getResponsableByCc(centroCosto);
            createNotificacion(responsable, notificador, mensaje);
            if (isUserForMail(responsable)) {
                destinatarios.add(responsable);
            }
        }

    }

    sendMailNewThread(destinatarios, notificador, mensaje);

    return result;
}

private void sendMailNewThread(final Set<User> destinatarios, final User notificador, final String mensaje) {

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendEMail(destinatarios, notificador, mensaje);
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();  
}
```

How can avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

you should not open Threads in a JavaEE context.

instead you should use [@Asynchronous](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)

```
public class EmailSender {

  @Resource("java:jboss/mail/Default")
  private Session mailSession;

  @Asynchronous
  public void sendNotification(String recipient) {
    // mail sending code
  }
}
```

and `@Inject` this into you controller. You then simply call `sendNotification` and it is executed in its own thread, but managed by the application server (which can in turn use thread pools, monitoring etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I got it,  doing Runnable r = new Runnable()  broke the context.
The correct way was to use an interface an inject it instead of instantiate the class like so:

```
@Inject
EmailSenderMt emailSenderMultithread;
```

and then:

emailSenderMultithread.setParameters(destinatarios, notificador, mensaje);

```
    Thread t = new Thread(emailSenderMultithread);
    t.start();
```

you can not instantiate any class that in it has an injection, but instead inject it, so

NO new Object();
but

@Inject
Object object;

if Object use any @Inject

Answer (score 0):

The exception message:

> No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

indicates that you refer to an object which is managed by your CDI (Weld?) from the Thread.

You should not make references to any Java objects which are managed by CDI (Weld?) from the thread. I would advise you to use POJOs only in the thread.

The other solution could be changing the scope of the referenced object from javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped to javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped - but do it only if this object is thread safe!